# How can I represent a space at the end of a span of code in markdown?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, markdown, markup

I'm trying to represent a short inline span of code with a significant space or two at the end, using [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax). If I were to put it in a stand-alone code block, it might look like this:

`cd`

Frustratingly, Markdown transforms `` `cd  ` `` into `<code>cd</code>`, deleting the space at the end. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I'm not aware of a way to do this with backticks in vanilla Markdown. If you need to use your current parser, you can use literal `<code>` HTML tags to generate correct output:

```
Normal text. <code>Inline code block with a space: </code> Normal text.
```

If you're able and interested, switching to a more consistent/expanded parser (such as kramdown, which I've tested, but potentially also MultiMarkdown and others) correctly interprets terminal spaces in code blocks and doesn't truncate them.

Answer (score -2):

I don't believe markdown has anything for that specifically but if you use `&nbsp;` it will add a non breaking space.  In your case replace

```
`cd  `
```

with

```
`cd&nbsp;&nbsp;`
```

and it should work as intended.

Comment: Nope. That produces `<code>cd&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;</code>`